# Как добавить колонку в бд django

Tags: django, база-данных

При входе в администрирование django и переходе в созданную таблицу отображается ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После ошибки я добавил новую колонку в models.py и выполнил:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

После этого ошибка все равно осталась. Подскажите, что делать. Я только начал изучать программирование.